# Why doesn't mongoose's .find({}) method do anything at all?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

**The Problem:**

I have a basic express server with a mongoose model.

I call the api '/api/forums/all' and it should get me all forum documents from the 'forum' model.

When I call it, it does nothing at all.

Here is my forums route itself:

```
router.get('/all', (req, res) => {
  // Populating all field we need in the frontend
  // We need: All the forums, with all subForums
  // and for each subForum we need it's posts and last poast

  console.log('trying..');
  const all = await Forum.find({}, (err, forum) => {
    console.log('still trying');
  });

  // .populate({
  //   path: 'subForums',
  //   populate: [{ path: 'lastPost' }, { path: 'posts' }]
  // });

  return res.json(all);
});
```

This is what gets printed when I try to access this route:

> trying..

So the "still trying" doesn't run.

**What have I tried:**

I changed the function to look like that (with asyinc before `(req, res)`:

```
try {
    console.log('trying..');
    const all = await Forum.find({})

    console.log('still trying');

    // .populate({
    //   path: 'subForums',
    //   populate: [{ path: 'lastPost' }, { path: 'posts' }]
    // });

    return res.json(all);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('trying but error');
    return res.json(err);
  }
```

And also with `.exec()` at the end of the `.find` method.

But "still trying" just won't run.

The get request with postman is just indefinitely running.

I really don't know what the problem could be at this point.

Comment: Have you called `mongoose.connect` somewhere?

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes I call it in my `index.js` file where I also set up all the routes.

Comment: Can you add you schema for `Forum`?

Comment: Of course:

`const forumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  subTitle: String,
  posts: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }],
  subForums: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subforum' }]
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error:

I was importing a seeder file that seeds the database and then disconnects it after it's finished.

So mongoose was not connected anymore when I called any routes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. When searching on db you need to first open mongodb

```
MongoClient.connect('url of your database', function(err, db) {
const all = await Forum.find({}, (err, forum) => {
    console.log('still trying');
  });
})
```

Comment: I open the connection to the database in my `index.js` file from my server like this:

`mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECT,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true },
  () => {
    console.log('connected DB');
  }
);`

This is my github repo if you want to check the full code out: https://github.com/SelfDevTV/forum-creator